# Updating appengine Entiy not reliable

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I tried updating my appengine entity by simply overwriting it with a newer value. It displays correctly in the data store viewer, but when I try to retrieve it in my app, it sometimes gives the older value, and sometimes newer.
I am using Objectify

```
@ApiMethod(name = "saveUser")
    public void saveUser(User user) {

        ofy().save().entity(user).now();
    }

@ApiMethod(name = "getUser")
    public User getUser(@Named("gdgId") Long id) {

        return ofy().load().type(User.class).id(id).now();
    }
```

So I call, save user when I want to insert/update the user and I call getUser to retrieve the user object associated with the id.
I am not using caching (@Cache annotation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you have the `ObjectifyFilter` installed in your application. I would suggest this looks like eventual consistency, but you are performing a get-by-key operation which will be strongly consistent. So it looks like session cache bleed-through caused by missing the filter.

Answer (score 1):

From Objectify documentation:

> Each Objectify instance holds a cache of entities which have been
>   loaded in that session. This prevents subsequent loads within that
>   session from needing to go out to the datastore. The cache holds
>   entity instances and (with the exception of transactions) will
>   consistently return the same actual object instance.
>
> This cache is separate from the global memcache enabled/disabled with
>   the @Cache annotation and the Objectify.cache() parameter.

Note that omitting @Cache annotation will not disable this caching behavior.

Comment: ofy().clear() :
Clears the session; all subsequent requests (or Ref<?>.get() calls) will go to the datastore/memcache to repopulate the session. This should rarely, if ever be necessary. Note that if you iterate query results you should only perform this action on chunk boundaries, otherwise performance will suffer. This is a "use only if you really know what you are doing" feature.

Is it a good idea to call this function, each time I save my user ? I think that removing the cache after saving should do the job ?

Comment: It should not be necessary. Try loading your user using a key. It's possible that you face a different problem - eventual consistency in the Datastore.